# Re-Configuring TCP IP of an AIX system ( LPAR P770/AIX 5.3)

Tags: tcpip, ibm, aix

I have `serverA` and `serverB` (AIX LPARS on SystemP)

I want to switch *hostname and IP* configurations between `serverA` and `serverB`.
Is it enough to perform the changes via `smitty mktcpip` or do I have to make changes via the HMC ( **H**ardware **M**anagement **C**onsole)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to configure the LPARs. The HMC is intended to change the "hardware" of the LPARs only, i.e. the number of processors, the amount of memory, these kinds of things.

You can use the HMC to open a console to the LPAR, with which you can safely play with network configuration, without the possibility to lock yourself out. Apart from this, the HMC is not needed for such a change.